# Can't seem to get proper response from my request

Tags: php, javascript, json, dojo, request

Here is the ajax/dojo i use to call my PHP file, request to get data from the database table:

```
     var _getWeatherInfo = function(){
     dojo.xhrget({

         url: "PHP/weather.php?ntown=" + _ntown,

         handleAs: "json",
         timeout: 5000,

         response: function(response, weather_info) {
            _refreshWeatherList 
         },          
         error: function(error_msg, weather_info) {
             _handleError(error_msg);
         }
     });
 }
```

The next bit of code below here is what i use to look through the returned json array object (which is now as "weather_info" in the javascript file) and add the data from the object to my javascript array called "_weather".

```
    var _refreshWeatherList = function(weather_info) {
        for (var i = 0; i < weather_info.length; i++) {
        _weather.push(weather_info[i]);
    }
 }
```

MY PROBLEM IS:

I dont think I am actually getting a proper response from my PHP request, as when I run my app and click the button i've used to alert the "_weather" array nothing is displayed. How can I change my code so it properly gets a response from my request.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: PHP:

```
<?php   

$ntown = $_GET['ntown'];

$weather = array();

$query="SELECT * FROM `weather` WHERE `town` = '$ntown'";
$result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Query to get data from table failed: ".mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {

    $weather = $row;
}

echo json_encode($weather);

mysql_close();
```

?>

Comment: You can use console.log(response) to get what is being sent by the php in console

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is just a typo, I think your problem is in this bit:

```
     response: function(response, weather_info) {
        _refreshWeatherList 
     },
```

Try changing it to:

```
     load: function(response) {
        _refreshWeatherList(response); 
     }, 
     // or just load: _refreshWeatherList
```

To debug problems like this, learn to use your browser's developer tools. In Firefox, use Tools -> Web developer -> Web console, or in Chrome click F12 and select the Network tab. (Other browsers usually have similar tools.) These will tell you about any requests being made, and clicking on the request will allow you to see the response, headers etc.

Comment: Hi, I had tried running it as load: but it had the same problem

Comment: I have changed it back to load:, I run my program through WAMP and use firebug console and I'm not getting any errors, but im also not getting my array displayed. As i mentioned in my OP, I think i'm not getting the json array sent to the javascript properly.

Comment: @Corey Do you see a request being made in firebug? Does it return the expected values? If you put `console.debug(response);` inside the load function, does anything interesting show up in the firebug console?

Comment: Hi, "response is not defined" unfortunately for me, this doesn't really mean much other then what i've said before, im not getting a response from my php to my javascript.

Comment: @Corey But what *does* your PHP return to your Javascript? You can see the request's response in the firebug log. Is it valid JSON?

Comment: As i said before, im not sure im getting ANYTHING back from my PHP, that is the whole reason for this question... I've used the debug console and im not getting any errors but im also not finding anything to suggest im gettign a response. This is what i need help with... I've added my php code to OP

Comment: This can be shortened to `load: _refreshWeatherList`.

Comment: @Corey Okay, I may have misunderstood, I thought you had narrowed it down to a problem in Javascript. If firebug shows no content in the response, the error is like you say presumably in your PHP script. Make sure you have error_reporting etc turned on in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the php code:

```
$weather = $row;
```

should be

```
$weather[] = $row;
```

Comment: isn't that just going to create and array inside of an array?

Comment: no, i want to be able to access my json_encoded array in my javascript function. At the moment it doesnt seem to be happening